# iOS Swift Tabbed Bar Application

Tags: swift, xcode

I am developing an application using Swift3 and Xcode 8.2.1. In my application there is a single view controller "StartUp" which is my initial view controller and a Tabbed bar controller which has three tabs named: Vehicles, History, Alarms.

I want to go in Vehicle tab activity from my StartUp "Single View Activity".

What I have tried?

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Vehicles") as! Vehicles
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It do take me on Vehicle tab activity but without Tabbed Bar controller.(Like a single view controller)

My question is How can I navigate from Single view StartUp activity to Vehicle Tabbed Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the UITabBarController.
Simply replace "Vehicles" with the UITabBarController identifier.
Then you can select a Tab of the UITabBarController.

In your case, you don't have to. Because Vehicles seems to be default.

Comment: Yes, That resolved my problem. Actually, I tried it before posting question but there was some casting error and now it's working properly. BTW thanks for help and early response.

Comment: Please set your question to "answered". Many people, like me, use the "find unanswered questions" tab to help people. It's time waste for us, to read posts that were already answered.